# MSVC2015 not detected when installed via 2019 build tools

Tags: visual-studio, docker, msbuild

I am trying to create a windows docker container for a VS2015 C++ build. I found some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019) how to install build tools in a container and it works for VS2017.

However, when trying to setup the 2015 version, MSBuild.exe complains that it cannot find v140 and despite adding `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v140` to the `vs_buildtools.exe` call. I also was not able to find any v140 `cl.exe` in any of the subfolders.

Obviously, GUI based solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33154696/760746) are not an option.

Here is my changed Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.8.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
ARG BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=16

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/${BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CLI.Support `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v140 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# put MSBuild.exe on PATH
RUN setx path "%path%;C:\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Comment: try this: `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140`

Comment: Did it work eventually for you? I have the exact same problem with server core in docker but it's not building, I am getting a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MSVC2015 not detected when installed via 2019 build tools

**Build Tool for VS2019** can install **v140 build tool for VS2015** so far.

[image]

The main issue is that you use the wrong Component ID for v140 build tool.

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#c-build-tools) said, you should use

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140`.

**Solution**

Use this:

`--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140` rather than `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v140`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I thought I had copied the Component ID for v140 directly from the page you linked. But I probably started with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64` from an earlier trial and just edited it to v140, not noticing that the naming scheme is slightly different.

Comment: I just wanted to verify it worked before upvoting/accepting. Now MSBuild complains that it cannot find SDK 8.1 which is not even listed for the 2019 Build Tools...

Comment: Actually, the latest `Build Tool for VS2019` does not  contain `SDK 8.1`.  If you also want to use SDK 8.1, I suggest you could install Build Tool for VS2017 which contains `SDK 8.1` and it also has `v140` build tool. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2017#visual-c-build-tools).

Comment: Use [this download link](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads).

Comment: Fur future reference: To successfully get SDK 8.1 working with `Build Tools for VS2017`  I needed to install the optional components `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Win81` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK` too.