# Failed to run MSBuild command on pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, msbuild, build-tools, scikit-survival

I am installing the scikit-survival package in Python. When I run

```
pip install scikit-survival
```

I get an error on msbuild, I attach the elements of interest below:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install scikit-survival     
                                                              
..
Building wheels for collected packages: qdldl                                                                             
Building wheel for qdldl (setup.py) ... error                                                                           
error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                                                                                                                                                             
× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.                                                                 
│ exit code: 1                                                                                                          
╰─> [24 lines of output]                                                                                                    
running bdist_wheel                                                                                                     
running build                                                                                                           
running build_ext                                                                                                       
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.22000.                                                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):                                                                                
Failed to run MSBuild command:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
MSBuild.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Impossibile trovare il file specification                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                                             
See also "C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-
uyja9anj/qdldl_c05b02902dbe43b69e2860ddcf14a11a/c/build/CMakeFiles/CMak
eOutput.log".                                                                                                  
Impossibile trovare il file specification                                                                                 
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: 
MSBuild.exe qdldlamd.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /v:m &&                                                                   
building 'qdldl' extension                                                                                              
cl : warning della riga di comando D9002 : l'opzione sconosciuta '-
std=c++11' verr… ignorata                            qdldl.cpp                                                                                                               
c\qdldl/include/qdldl.h(5): fatal error C1083: Non Š possibile aprire 
il file inclusione: 'qdldl_types.h': No such file or directory                                                                                                            
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x
64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2                                                                            
[end of output]                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
...
```

The issue is with MSbuild.exe. Do you know how it can be solved? I have installed both Visual Studio Community with Python extensions and Visual Studio Build Tools.

Comment: You could create a bug report for scikit-survival or qldl because that's where the build fails. A possibly easier solution: install scikit-survival with conda, see https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would like to avoid conda. I will try to ask to scikit-survival or qldl.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your're using the **wrong VisualStudio version**. As mentioned in the Make command error VisualStudioVersion should be 14.0 (which is Visual Studio 2015), your Visual Studio Version is 2022 (VisualStudioVersion=22.X).

CMake and the different VS Versions as well as the different SDKs are a little bit confusing.

**What helped me:**

In the Visual Studio Installer, Modify your VisualStudio Installation as mentioned in the top comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154696/msbuild-error-the-builds-tools-for-v140-platform-toolset-v140-cannot-be-f). (*Desktop development with C++ > Optional > MSVC v140 - VS 2015, should be at the bottom of the list*)

If you're running in another error (which happened to me) you might have to install Windows SDK 8.1

There might be a way to change the Visual Studio Version for CMake, since the steps above helped me I haven't had a look at another solution.

Please let me know if this helps or if there is another problem.

Cheers.