# can't build old VS2010 project with VS2013. (build tool for VS2010 cannot be found.)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda, msbuild

I have installed VS2013 on my computer about 2 years ago(and removed VS2010 I guess) and today I tried to open my old VS2010 project (MV1.sln) that I used to work with about 5 years ago. 
When I tried to open it, it just says "more than one project in the solution was not loaded correctly. refer to the output window"(translated from Korean). The output window says

D:\My_Path\MV1\MV1.vcxproj : error : can't read project file "MV1.vcxproj"
D:\My_Path\MV1\MV1.vcxproj(34,5): can't find imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props". Check if the path specified in <import> declaration is correct and file exists in the disk.

So I checked the MV1.vcxproj file's line 34 which reads

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props" />
```

which seems to be correct path because the value $(VCTargetsPath) is being used before line 34 in the same file and I can easily guess it points to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild (I can see Microsoft.Cpp.props folder and BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props file referred to in the .vcxproj file)
I had CUDA4.0.props file which specifies include path and library path for CUDA4.0 under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 (I kept those files there at that time) but copied it to the location specified in vcxproj file to make it appear there.
I found some similar questions and answers but they seem to be different from my case. What can be the most correct method other than making a new project and copying and specifying everything one-by-one?

Answer (score 1):

I found the file name should have a space in 'CUDA 4.0.props' so I changed the file name(MSBuild/Microsoft.Cpp/V120/BuildCustomizations/CUDA 4.0.targets) , then it complained about CUDA 4.0.targets file missing, so I copied MSBuild/Microsoft.Cpp/v4.0/BuildCustomizations/CUDA 4.0.targets (it was there since 5 years ago) to MSBuild/Microsoft.Cpp/v4.0/V120/BuildCustomizations/CUDA 4.0.targets. Now I can see the files in the project browser but when I build the project, it says

> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build
>   tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively,
>   you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the
>   Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade
>   Solution...". C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets  64  5   MV1

But in my VS2013 I don't see such "Upgrade Solution" or upgrade menu. So I looked for method to change the toolset and found 
[Visual Studio 2013 error MS8020 Build tools v140 cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792663/visual-studio-2013-error-ms8020-build-tools-v140-cannot-be-found) and seleted VS2013 and it tries to build now.
(though I have fix some errors cannot link external symbol _CUDAInit.. etc.)