# is it possible to install v140 build tools in visual studio 2013? if yes then how?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild

I want to install v140 build tools in visual studio 2013, as my project has been upgraded to vs 2015. I dont want to install vs 2015. is there a way to install v140 in vs 2013. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I tried to install the build tools, but the installation failed. I asked the same question [on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/641fd2f9-d3a3-454f-aeb5-6fe8ea5aad25/build-tools-v140-not-loading-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=msbuild) and was told that VS is backward compatible but not forward compatible with build tool installs.

So, no—it is not possible to install v140 of the build tools on VS 2013, as this is an older version of Visual Studio than v140.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible!
It is that simple, but I am forced to write at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the Visual C++ 2015 build tools from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).

You can then change your toolset (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792663/visual-studio-2013-error-ms8020-build-tools-v140-cannot-be-found)):

- Right click your project, go to Properties.
- Under Configuration Properties, go to General.
- Change your Platform Toolset to one of the
  available ones.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! I had downloaded and installed build tools from the link given by you, but when i want to change platform toolset v140 toolset isn't showing up in the drop down menu.

Comment: It is not possible. Build tools are for backwards compatibility, like VS2017 compiling VS2015. But it is not possible forward so I downvoted your answer.